# Align text center below the icon in a table td (multiple icons)

Tags: css, sass

I have the following code:

```
 <td>
   <a class="action--edit"><i class="icon-edit">Edit</i></a>
   <a class="action--delete"><i class="icon-delete">Delete</i></a>
  </td>
```

What I need:

1. Align each action anchor near each other in the center of td (done - keep this way)
2. The anchor text to go below the icon (i) and both be centered in anchor

What I tried:

```
[class^=table--] td a i { display: block }
```

Then I added span for text:

```
<td>

   <a class="action--edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i><span>Edit</span></i></a>
   <a class="action--delete"><i class="icon-delete"></i><span>Delete</span></a>
  </td>



 [class^=table--] td a i, [class^=table--] td a span {
        display: block; }
```

The icon, i is a font icon:

```
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: "c" !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

In both cases, the anchors change on above the other, and not what I need:

- anchor near each other
- text under icon

I didn't tried float on anchor(a) because is in td an need to be centered

See below image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your image, something like this? Icons need to be blocks with auto margin so text can drop below.

```css
html,body {
  font: normal 100%/1 sans-serif;
}
.btn-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 65px; /* Optional to keep buttons same size */
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn-icon i {
  font-size: 28px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.btn-icon:hover {
  color: blue;
  background: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make `anchor` tag content to align `center`.

```css
td {
  min-width: 150px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

td i,
td span {
  display: block;
}

td a {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body>
  <table>
    <td>

      <a class="action--edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i><span>Edit</span></a>
      <a class="action--delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i><span>Delete</span></a>
    </td>
  </table>
</body>
```